# Moving a word backwards in Vim?

Tags: vim, navigation

To move a word forward in Vim, you press `w` or `e`. How can I move a word *backwards*?

Comment: The Vim tutor (vimtutor) is a great place to start if you want to learn the basics.

Comment: I've been through it. I couldn't find how to move a word backwards.

Comment: You are right, find that a bit strange. Think it should be included in the motion short list in Lesson 2.3.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To move backwards by a word, type `b`. The backwards equivalent of `e` is `ge`. See

```
:help word-motions
```

Comment: well cheers, mate.